# Given an array of objects, create a function that returns an Object that has an array of paths grouped by type

Tags: javascript

I have an Array of objects as follows:

```
var data = [
  {name : 'xxxx' , type: 'jpeg' , path: '../'},
  {name : 'yyyy' , type: 'gif' , path: '../'},
  {name : 'zzzz' , type: 'jpeg' , path: '../'}
];
```

I want the result to be in this format:

```
{
  jpeg: ['../xxxx.jpeg', '../zzzz.jpeg'],
  gif:['../yyyy.gif']
}
```

My attempt:

```
function transformData(data) {
    var result = {};
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            result[data[i].type] = [data[i].path + data[i].name];
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
}

transformData(data);
```

Comment: And ? What problems did you have ? Did you try to do it ?

Comment: i tried doing it but not getting the expected result.

Comment: Show your attempt so that we can help you find your bug.

Answer (score 1):

As there are a few answers, I'll give a functional one based on `reduce` :

```
var arr = data.reduce(function(r,m){
  (r[m.type]||(r[m.type]=[])).push(m.path+m.name+'.'+m.type);
  return r;
},{});
```

Comment: can not be used in IE8 or lower

Comment: @micha Well, yes of course, but I don't think we should still carry that weight in 2015.

Comment: but u should say it like in the other answer . maybe he dont want exclude ie8

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = [
  {name : 'xxxx' , type: 'jpeg' , path: '../'},
  {name : 'yyyy' , type: 'gif' , path: '../'},
  {name : 'zzzz' , type: 'jpeg' , path: '../'}
];   

var res = {},
    len = data.length, i;


for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (!res[data[i].type]) {
    res[data[i].type] = [];
  }

  res[data[i].type].push(data[i].path + data[i].name + '.' + data[i].type);
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/hupoco/2/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function for elegant solution.

```
// Your data
var data = [
  {name : 'xxxx' , type: 'jpeg' , path: '../'},
  {name : 'yyyy' , type: 'gif' , path: '../'},
  {name : 'zzzz' , type: 'jpeg' , path: '../'}
];

// Solution
var res = data.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    ((prev[current.type])||(prev[current.type] = [])).push( current.path + current.name + '.' + current.type );
    return prev;
}, {});

// console.log( res );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using `forEach`:

```
var data = [
  {name : 'xxxx' , type: 'jpeg' , path: '../'},
  {name : 'yyyy' , type: 'gif' , path: '../'},
  {name : 'zzzz' , type: 'jpeg' , path: '../'}
];

var result = {};

data.forEach(function(elem){
    result[elem.type] = result[elem.type] || [];
    result[elem.type].push(elem.path + elem.name + '.' + elem.type);
});
```

Keep in mind that [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) can not be used in IE8 or lower, but the mdn page has some polyfills for that.

Comment: Guys, what's with the downvote? Is something broken?